# 301 redirect occurs although redirect is not specified and condition is not meet in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use the `.htaccess` file to simplify urls for my domain. I have one rule which simply adds a slash to the end of the url if there isn't one already:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

So I put the `R=301` in the end so that it redirects to the new url so that the user gets to sees this change. The next line then searches for a specific pattern to rewrite it to a proper url format as such:

```
RewriteRule ^account/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /account.php?prefix=$1 [NC,L]
```

So the idea is that if this url is called:

```
http://example.com/account/user123
```

Then it first sent a '301' to redirect to:

```
http://example.com/account/user123/
```

and then sends a '200' and internal rewrites to:

```
 http://example.com/account.php?prefix=user123
```

The problem that I have is that for some reason it first adds the slash without a problem and returns a `301` to the new url with the slash but then it calls a `301` again to redirect the browser to:

```
http://example.com/account.php?prefix=user123
```

I don't understand why it would do so because the ending of the `RewriteRule` that handles this has `L` in it and does not contain an `R` so to my understanding it would only internally rewrite the url without sending a redirect to the client.

So obviously I did some bug fixing before resorting to ask this question and I discovered that if I comment out the lines of code that add the slash:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$)
#RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

I know that the problem must be somewhere here because without specification the .htaccess returns a `302` instead of a `301` but the second rewrite does not contain this specification. So the second rewrite somehow calls the `R=301` from the previous line although that one does not match.

I have no idea what is going wrong here and my analyses of the problem might be wrong. Im completely confused by what is happening here, please help XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule with the 301 does match, as `account.php` does not end with a `/`. Even after an internal rewrite all RewriteRules are processed again.

You could add another RewriteCond before it to not apply if a file with the name exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```